# How can I combine two String[] Arrays into a 2D ArrayList using Java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

How can I combine the following two `string[]` arrays into a two dimensional `ArrayList`?

```
private String[] titles = {
        "Apple", "Orange", "Banana"};

private String[] details = {
        "Red Fruit", "Orange Citrus Fruit", "Yellow Fruit"};
  //In reality, these data sets are full.
```

It needs to fit in a wrapper class. The methods need to look like this, in order to be compatible with the other classes.

```
private ArrayList<DataObject> getDataSet() {
    ArrayList results = new ArrayList<>();
    return results; //Just a rough view of the class. 
}
```

The output should be two-dimensional `ArrayList` with `String[] titles` at the 1st dimension and `String[] details` at the 2nd one.

Essentially

```
results.add("Apple", "Red Fruit");
```

and do it for all the items in titles and details.

Comment: I don't understand what is the question, can you please explain? If you need a shorter way to do it, you might want to take a look at [lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/)

Comment: @BackSlash I need to combine two String[] to one ArrayList.  It needs to be compatible with their formatting for it to work

Comment: The edited question is still unclear. Can you give examples on what kind of output you are expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting them to be combined into a two dimensional array list. I can't really make the question clearer. Somehow, fluffyBatman was able to understand what I was asking and provide a working piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we go to the way of your provided sample then this should do.

```
private ArrayList<DataObject> mess() {
    ArrayList results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int index = 0; index < titles.length; index++) {
        DataObject obj = new DataObject(titles[index],
                details[index]);
        results.add(index, obj);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Note that, if these two arrays(titles and details) of yours have different length then this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive by using below lines of code

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.addAll(Arrays.asList(titles));
a.addAll(Arrays.asList(details));
```